Draw edges with changing edge width between two nodes
I would like to represent edges that convey the strength of some parameters between two edges for visual representation, preferably using python/vis.js/d3.js. While I could use edge labels, given the density of the graphs, this would be a more useful approach. However, I could not find any way to plot such graphs. I use python, vis.js and d3.js and willing to explore any other approach as well. I would be grateful for any suggestions on this. An other pythonic approach, such as edgegradiant available for R, would be the second best option.

